# Easiest way to make a skeleton screen when data is loading

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and i am trying to make something that looks like in the example included in the snippet.
What is the easiest way to do this with dart and flutter.

basically i want to apply a shine animation to a container when the data from the server is still being downloaded.

Thanks

```css
div {
    margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px; /* change height to see repeat-y behavior */
    
  background-image:
   radial-gradient( circle 50px at 50px 50px, lightgray 99%, transparent 0 ),
   linear-gradient( 100deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80% ),
   linear-gradient( lightgray 20px, transparent 0 ),
   linear-gradient( lightgray 20px, transparent 0 ),
   linear-gradient( lightgray 20px, transparent 0 ),
   linear-gradient( lightgray 20px, transparent 0 );

  background-repeat: repeat-y;

  background-size:
   100px 200px, /* circle */
   50px 200px, /* highlight */
   150px 200px,
   350px 200px,
   300px 200px,
   250px 200px;

  background-position:
   0 0, /* circle */
   0 0, /* highlight */
   120px 0,
   120px 40px,
   120px 80px,
   120px 120px;

  animation: shine 1s infinite;
 }

 @keyframes shine {
  to {
   background-position:
    0 0,
    100% 0, /* move highlight to right */
    120px 0,
    120px 40px,
    120px 80px,
    120px 120px;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can combine a `Stack` and `Positioned.fill` with a `FractionallySizedBox` to position such gradient on the top of another widget.

Then you can combine it to an `AnimationController`, an `AnimatedBuilder` and an `Align` or `FractionallySizedBox` to animate the position of the gradient over time.

You'd have this :

```
class LoadAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  LoadAnimation({@required this.child, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoadAnimationState createState() => _LoadAnimationState();
}

class _LoadAnimationState extends State<LoadAnimation>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    )..repeat();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        widget.child,
        Positioned.fill(
          child: ClipRect(
              child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: controller,
            builder: (context, child) {
              return FractionallySizedBox(
                widthFactor: .2,
                alignment: AlignmentGeometryTween(
                  begin: Alignment(-1.0 - .2 * 3, .0),
                  end: Alignment(1.0 + .2 * 3, .0),
                ).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOut)).evaluate(controller),
                child: child,
              );
            },
            child: const DecoratedBox(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: const LinearGradient(
                  colors: const [
                    Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255),
                    Colors.white,
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Which you can then use by wrapping any given widget :

```
LoadAnimation(
  child: Container(
    height: 100.0,
    width: 200.0,
    color: Colors.lime,
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: you just need to implement the dispose method and dispose  the animation controller, and your answer would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Although Rèmi posted a very nice solution, this package should also be mentioned: https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer